# StoryTime cms user model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, content-management-system

In setting up the Storytime cms (https://github.com/FlyoverWorks/storytime), I want to use my Admin model as the user model.  In the storytime.rb initialiser I declare config.user_class = 'Admin' and if I look at Storytime.user_class then it returns my Admin class. However, when I go to my home page then I get an exception in line 14 of the storytime application controller:

`elsif current_user.nil?`

which is not surprising as I do not have a user model.  The admin model was set up using Devise. If I go to /storytime, I get a similar error, but in that case an undefined method for authenticate_user!.

How do I set up Storytime to use my Admin model as the user?

Answer (score 2):

It appears that Devise creates distinct current_* methods for use within controllers and views based on the Devise models that were created. The *User* class corresponds to **current_user**, while an *Admin* class would correspond to **current_admin**.

In your case, Storytime is returning *nil* because it is looking for the *User* class instead of the Storytime.user_class [*Admin*] that was inputted.

I filed an issue on [Github](https://github.com/FlyoverWorks/storytime/issues/55) and will take a deeper look into resolving the issue shortly.

**Updated: This issue should be fixed in Storytime 1.0.6!**